# How to add custom "filter" to Conv2D layer in Keras

Tags: keras

My research project requires me to add few custom "filters" to the Conv2D layer in Keras (Apart from the filters that Conv2D trained itself). How can I achieve this? Can I achieve this by building any "custom layer"? If yes, can anyone point me towards resources that help me achieve this?

I tried understanding the Conv2D code in github but failed to understand where and how it is handling it's filters.

I am expecting to find a way to add my custom filter say .. [[1 0 0][0 1 0][0 0 1]] to a conv2d layer so that during prediction it convolves the image with the filter that I supplied.

Answer (score 1):

In keras it is simple.

Let's have an example. Suppose we want to apply our custom filter onto an input matrix(image)-

[image]

**Necessary import**

```py
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras import Input, layers
from keras.models import Model
```

**Definition of the *custom filter***

[image]

```py
# custom filter
def my_filter(shape, dtype=None):

    f = np.array([
            [[[1]], [[0]], [[-1]]],
            [[[1]], [[0]], [[-1]]],
            [[[1]], [[0]], [[-1]]]
        ])
    assert f.shape == shape
    return K.variable(f, dtype='float32')
```

**Dummy example input image** (1 channel)

```py
input_mat = np.array([
    [ [4], [9], [2], [5], [8], [3] ],
    [ [3], [6], [2], [4], [0], [3] ],
    [ [2], [4], [5], [4], [5], [2] ],
    [ [5], [6], [5], [4], [7], [8] ],
    [ [5], [7], [7], [9], [2], [1] ],
    [ [5], [8], [5], [3], [8], [4] ]
])
input_mat = input_mat.reshape((1, 6, 6, 1))
```

**Dummy conv model** where we will use our custom filter

```py
def build_model():
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(6,6,1))
    x = layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size = 3,
                      kernel_initializer=my_filter,
                      strides=2, padding='valid') (input_tensor)
    model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=x)
    return model
```

**Testing**

```py
model = build_model()
out = model.predict(input_mat)
print(out)
```

**Output**

```
[[[[ 0.]
   [-4.]]

  [[-5.]
   [ 3.]]]]
```